# Modelling a user ranking system with NoSQL technologies

Tags: database-design, architecture, nosql, ranking, system-design

How would you model a system that ranks users based on the row creation date in a world-wide scale? Entries can only be added/removed once a day (as in a batch, for example). And the following requirements/facts must be observed:

- No relational database systems can be used
- The response time for a query should be ~ 1 second (a `query` in a system like this means something like: `fetch what's the ranking of user XYZ`)
- We're talking about something around 10MM users world-wide

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more please :) What's the number of reads we're expecting per day? Heavy loads? Is row creation date the addition date? Does that mean (since you've mentioned we can only add stuff with a batch job) we can have N records with the same ranking? Are we looking to retrieve individual records of ranking or batches of ranking (ex: top 1000 ranking accounts?) Also is relational DB allowed - or do we have to design with a NoSQL

Comment: You can use FoundationDB with ranked set, see https://github.com/FoundationDB/fdb-record-layer/blob/master/fdb-extensions/src/main/java/com/apple/foundationdb/async/RankedSet.java